# Passing data to "unknown" viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have lots of viewcontrollers, spread over many storyboards.

Is there any way to pass data to a viewcontroller, when only knowing the viewcontroller identifier.

The viewcontroller identifier and storyboard name is is read from a plist, and the viewcontroller is loaded like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: plistdata.storyboard, bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: menuItem.identifier)
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Since i cant cast the viewcontroller as the proper class, i cant set the data. Can a class be casted from a string, something like

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: menuItem.identifier) as! ClassFromString("MyDestinationViewController")
```

Or would it be a better approach to have the datamodel keep track of which viewcontroller is being pushed, and fetch the necessary data in the destination viewcontroller as soon as it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't know the class of something, but you want to be able to talk to it anyway, that's what a protocol is for. If every one of your anonymous view controller classes adopts MyProtocol, and if MyProtocol requires a `takeData` method, then you can cast `vc` to a MyProtocol and call `takeData` with no further information about what class this view controller is.

Answer (score 0):

I think Best approach is Segue... Because Segue make Array of your ViewControllers so it is easy to push, pop, and send data.